# Deleting all records in a table in mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql

How would i remove all records from a given mysql table using jdbc in java.

Comment: better learn some SQL stuff... it is really bad question buddy.... you can find lot of tutorial over internet... learn them and replace your "Select *" Part in your Java code with the Query you learned...

Comment: yeah. Am working on it. Am extremely new to sql.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By executing the following query -

```
DELETE    
FROM   your_table_name;
```

If you also want to know how to use JDBC, then go [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html).

Comment: This does not delete the column name which i added.

Comment: @user1092042: If you execute this query, then every row, that means every record from the `your_table_name` will be deleted. You didn't say anything about `columns` in your question. Are you trying to delete/drop columns from your table?

Comment: My mistake. I got confused. Thanks fro your help